# How to apply multiple transforms to snippet variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm in a file called `event-list.tsx`, and I'm trying to create a snippet that writes the following code:

```
const EventList: FC = () => {
  return <div>
    
  </div>;
};

export default EventList;
```

Thus far, in `typescriptreact.json` I've written the following snippet setting, which results in awkward-looking code (it puts out `const event-list` rather than `const EventList`

```
"react arrow func component": {
    "prefix": "rafce",
    "body": [
      "const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE}: FC = () => {",
      "  return <div>",
      "    ",
      "  </div>;",
      "};",
      "",
      "export default ${TM_FILENAME_BASE};",
      ""
    ]
  },
```

I know how to remove the hyphen from the snippet:
`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/-//}`
I also figured out how to capitalize the first character:
`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^.)/${1:/upcase}/}`

But I can't figure out how to apply all three of the changes I want. I know the regular expression needed to capitalize every character that comes after a hyphen (a positive lookbehind), but I don't know how to apply it here. There is nothing in the [documentation chapter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) implying the possibility to chain multiple transforms onto each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following global regex

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.)([^-]*)-?/${1:/upcase}${2}/g}
```

Find a part before a `-` and Upcase the first letter, repeat for the whole string

Answer (score 1):

`"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w+)-?/${1:/capitalize}/g}",`

`(\\w+)-?` : You only need one capture group if you use `/capitalize`.

The hyphens are removed by virtue of matching them (`-?`) but not including them in the output.

The `g` flag is necessary to keep matching every `(\\w+)-?` instance and perform a transform for each.

And since you are reusing an earlier transform you can simplify the whole thing like this:

```
"react arrow func component": {
  "prefix": "rafce",
  "body": [
    "const ${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w*)-?/${1:/capitalize}/g}}: FC = () => {",
    "  return <div>",
    "    ",
    "  </div>;",
    "};",
    "",
    "export default $1;",
    ""
  ]
},
```

Note that

`${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w*)-?/${1:/capitalize}/g}}`

stores the result of that transform in variable `$1` - which can simply be used later (or earlier) by itself to output the same result!